# Deploying to Weblogic with javax.naming.NameNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, email, tomcat, weblogic12c

We are trying to successfully deploy a Spring 3.2.6 application that was developed on Tomcat 6 to Weblogic 12.1.2.  The application works fine in Tomcat.  The application is calling the Mail Connection Service on Tomcat (mail-1.4.7.jar).  On Tomcat the library(mail jar) resides in the tomcat/lib and in Weblogic we put it in app/oracle/admin/domains/devtest_domain/lib folder.

This is the applicationContext.xml:

```
<!-- Data Source using JNDI -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="resourceRef">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>${datasource.JndiName.DS}</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="mailService" class="com.xxxx.xxxx.utils.MailService">
    <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
</bean>

<bean id="mailSender"
      class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="session" ref="mailSession" />
</bean>

<!-- Mail Session using JNDI -->
<bean id="mailSession" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="resourceRef">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>${mailSession.JndiName}</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The property file contents are:

```
#Datasource
datasource.JndiName.DS=java:comp/env/jdbc/xxxx
#MailSession
mailSession.JndiName=java:comp/env/mail/xxxx
```

When we run the deployment we see the following exception in the log:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'forgotPasswordAction': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.xxx.xxxx.utils.MailService com.xx.xx.action.ForgotPasswordAction.mailService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailService' defined in file [/u01/app/oracle/admin/domains/devtest_domain/servers/WLS_DEV1/stage/xx-dev/xxx-dev/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mailSender' while setting bean property 'mailSender'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailSender' defined in file [/u01/app/oracle/admin/domains/devtest_domain/servers/WLS_DEV1/stage/xx-dev/xx-dev/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mailSession' while setting bean property 'session'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailSession' defined in file 
[/u01/app/oracle/admin/domains/devtest_domain/servers/WLS_DEV1/stage/xxx-dev/xxxx-dev/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up comp/env/mail/xxxin /app/webapp/xxx-dev/1749454341.; remaining name 'comp/env/mail/xxx'
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailSession' defined in file [/u01/app/oracle/admin/domains/devtest_domain/servers/WLS_DEV1/stage/xxxx-dev/xxxx-dev/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up comp/env/mail/xxin /app/webapp/xxx-dev/1749454341.; remaining name 'comp/env/mail/xxx'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
```

I looked at the JNDI tree in Weblogic and no resource by the name 'comp/env/mail/xxx' exists.

Do we just need to configure JavaMail on the Weblogic like : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15586_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/mail/CreateMailSessions.html

Thanks in Advanced!

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to setup the mail resource in Weblogic, also the configuration file had to change to reflect the new JNDI resource for mail sessions in the Weblogic server too.

From 
mailSession.JndiName=java:comp/env/mail/xxxx
To
mailSession.JndiName=mail/xxxx

Thanks,

Tom